# Iterate nested object structure for specific element

Tags: javascript

I have following nested object. What would be the easiest way to get all "scope" values in an array without referring them individually like,

```
JSONObject["inc"]["scope"]
```

Object:

```
[{
    "inc": [{
        "type": "Entity",
        "scope": "A"
    }, {
        "type": "Entity",
        "scope": "B"
    }],
    "inv": [{
        "type": "Entity",
        "scope": "C"
    }],
    "oth": [{
        "type": "Entity",
        "scope": "D"
    }],
    "pro": [{
        "type": "Support Dept",
        "scope": "E"
    }, {
        "type": "Entity",
        "scope": "F"
    }, {
        "type": "Entity",
        "scope": "C"
    }],
    "ap": [{
        "type": "Support Dept",
        "scope": "A"
    }]
}]
```

Would appreciate any help on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```js
var obj = [{
  "inc": [{
    "type": "Entity",
    "scope": "A"
  }, {
    "type": "Entity",
    "scope": "B"
  }],
  "inv": [{
    "type": "Entity",
    "scope": "C"
  }],
  "oth": [{
    "type": "Entity",
    "scope": "D"
  }],
  "pro": [{
    "type": "Support Dept",
    "scope": "E"
  }, {
    "type": "Entity",
    "scope": "F"
  }, {
    "type": "Entity",
    "scope": "C"
  }],
  "ap": [{
    "type": "Support Dept",
    "scope": "A"
  }]
}];

var arr = [];
for (var i in obj[0]) {
  for (var j in obj[0][i]) {
    arr.push(obj[0][i][j]["scope"])
  }
}
console.log(arr)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you could do it:

```js
var obj = [{
    "inc": [{
        "type": "Entity",
        "scope": "A"
    }, {
        "type": "Entity",
        "scope": "B"
    }],
    "inv": [{
        "type": "Entity",
        "scope": "C"
    }],
    "oth": [{
        "type": "Entity",
        "scope": "D"
    }],
    "pro": [{
        "type": "Support Dept",
        "scope": "E"
    }, {
        "type": "Entity",
        "scope": "F"
    }, {
        "type": "Entity",
        "scope": "C"
    }],
    "ap": [{
        "type": "Support Dept",
        "scope": "A"
    }]
}];
    
res =  Object.keys(obj[0]).reduce(function (acc, key) {
    return acc.concat(obj[0][key].map (function (o) {
        return o.scope;
    }));
}, []);

console.log(res);
```

Please don't call your variable `JSONObject`. There is no such thing. JSON is a text format for data exchange. What you have is a JavaScript object, which might have been derived from JSON you parsed, but it is not JSON.

Comment: I am getting Syntax error on token ">", delete this token for "key => "

Comment: Running ie huh? use `function(key) {  return obj[0][key][0].scope }` . it shall work

Comment: also this will not give all the scope values. It will give the scope value only at index 0.

Comment: @Rishi, as you appear to run this in IE (which does support EcmaScript2015 arrow syntax), I modified the code accordingly. The remark of A.J taken into account as well.

Answer (score 1):

One approach i would take would be the functional approach.

**ES2015**

```js
let scopes = obj.reduce((start ,item) => {
  start = Object.keys(item).map(e => item[e]);
  return start.concat.apply([] , start).map( e => e.scope);
},[]);
console.log('ES2015',scopes);
```

**ES5**

```js
var scopes = obj.reduce(function(start ,item){
  start = Object.keys(item).map(function(e){
    return item[e];
  })
  return start.concat.apply([] , start).map(function(e){
    return e.scope
  });
},[]);

console.log('ES5',scopes)
```